# Is it possible to connect to a VPN (that lets more than one connection to it) on multiple sessions with one PC?

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn

I have a VPN account that lets me to connect to it simultaneously on multiple devices.
For example I can connect to it using both  my laptop and  mobile phone and yet each of them has the speed as like as I am connected just with it.

Can I connect to this VPN on multiple sessions using  *one* PC but with different user accounts or on a virtual Operating system (or something like that) ?

Comment: Most likely not. :(

Comment: What software are you using to VPN into the service?  Also, does it seamlessly combine the apps into the taskbar or just display the open applications in 1 window.

Comment: I just setup a VPN connection and connect to it . I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: There are different types of VPN software for example http://openvpn.net and Viscosity http://www.sparklabs.com/viscosity/.  You are typically assigned a user password and server.  Provides it follows the protocol you can VPN in from other VPN software.

Answer (score 0):

Not practically, unless you are really perverse.

Its not clear why you might want to do this (it won't allow you to get more then the maximum speed of your connection - ignoring the advantages of compression if enabled on a VPN, a VPN adds overhead and makes things slower - both throughput and latency wise then a raw pipe.)

I believe its not practical to do this for 2 reasons -

1. The tunnel server will have a single end point IP and port/set of ports/protocol, 
   and the PC will have a single IP address, thus causing problems with having 2 
   connections.   (You may be able to overcome this with some types of VPN, for example
   UDP tunnels with OpenVPN might just work, but I doubt you will have any luck with,
   for example PPTP)
2. The routing will be messy and complicated - you would need to work out how to balance
   the load doing source routing and possibly other tricks.

So, yes, it might just be doable in some cases, but I can't see a reason why you would do it practically.

Comment: Thanks. you mean that if I connect to it for example on a virtual OS as well as on main Os, I will not be able to download with twice the speed of one connection?(I have internet access through this VPN connection) . But if I can connect to it on 2 PCs I can download with each of them as the other doesn't exist.

Comment: Correct. The speed of the Internet is constrained by the speed of slowest connection between yourself and the content provider, and multiple VPNs won't overcome that limitation.   It appears like your connection may be oversubscribed by your you are far away (Internet links wise) from where you are getting content.  In both these cases you can probably get a speed boost buy opening up multiple connections to the site and downloading the files using multiple threads - You may want to ask another question on that and link to it, as the answer is to complex to fit into a comment.